# Why does getting text, val or html from a textarea get the placeholder value when there is no user created text?

Tags: html, textarea, placeholder

Why am I getting the placeholder value for my textarea if I have no text in the element?
Shouldn't I just be getting a empty string, and not the placeholder value?

Comment: Show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the example, it doesn't alert the placeholder-text.

```js
alert($('textarea').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="text" placeholder="this is a test"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you displaying the placeholder text? Some sources recommend something along the lines of this for placeholder text in a textarea:

```
<textarea>
PLACEHOLDER CONTENT
</textarea>
```

If this is the method you are using, the interior content will be treated as the value, not the placeholder. The proper route would be something along these lines:

```
<textarea placeholder="PLACEHOLDER CONTENT"></textarea>
```